Reference request for Bessel function of the second kind with matrix argument
As the title says, I would like to know if anyone could provide a reference which provides the definition and properties of the Bessel function of the second kind with matrix argument. If possible, I would appreciate as well any reference which provides its power series.

Because Bessel functions of the first and second kind are related by
$$Y_\nu(z)=\frac{J_\nu(z)\cos\pi\nu-J_{-\nu}(z)}{\sin \pi\nu},$$
you can refer to literature that studies the function $J_\nu$ with matrix argument:

Bessel Functions of Matrix Argument (1955)
Laplace approximation for Bessel functions of matrix argument (2003)

Section 7 of the 1955 paper gives the power series.
